# What is the relation between the Lagrange multipliers and the solution of the dual in a linear optimisation problem?

Tags: linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

Consider the following linear minimisation problem
$$
(1) \quad \min_{x\geq 0} a^\top x,\\
\quad \quad \quad \text{s.t. }B^\top x=c
$$
where

- $x$ is the $p\times 1$ vector of unknowns.
- $a$ is a $p\times 1$ vector of real numbers.
- $B$ is a $p\times k$ matrix of real scalars.
- $c$ is a $k\times 1$ vector of real scalars.
- $p>k$.

Consider the Lagrangian of (1)

$$
(2) \quad L(x,\mu,\nu)= a^\top x+\mu^{\top}\left(B^\top x-c\right)-\nu^{\top}x,
$$

Consider also the dual of (1)
$$
(3) \quad \max_{y} c^\top y,\\
\quad \quad \quad \text{s.t. } By \leq a
$$

**Question:** what is the relation between the dual of (1) and the Lagrange multipliers of (1)?

Let $\mathcal{X}^*$ be the set of argmin of (1).

Let $\mathcal{Y}^*$ be the set of argmax of (3).

Let $\mathcal{M}^*$ be the set of Lagrange multipliers $\mu$ corresponding to each element of $\mathcal{X}^*$.

Let $\mathcal{V}^*$ be the set of Lagrange multipliers $\nu$ corresponding to each element of $\mathcal{X}^*$.

Is $\mathcal{Y}^*=\mathcal{M}^*$? What is the relation between $\mathcal{Y}^*$ and $\mathcal{V}^*$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship is that $\mu=-y$ and $\nu$ is the slack variable in the constraint: $By + \nu = a$. You can obtain this by [deriving the dual from the Lagrangian](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eelghaoui/Teaching/EE227A/lecture7.pdf):
$$\min_x L(x,\mu,\nu)= \min_x \left\{ (a+B\mu-\nu)^\top x-\mu^{\top}c \right\}=\begin{cases}-\mu^Tc & \text{if } a+B\mu-\nu=0 \\ -\infty &\text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks. I have a related doubt that I'm unable to clarify. Consider the Lagrange dual problem $$\max_{\nu\geq 0, \mu}\min_x L(x,\nu,\mu)$$ Let $\tilde{\mathcal{V}}^*$ and $\tilde{\mathcal{M}^*}$ be the argmax of this problem wrto $\nu,\mu$. If I have understood correctly, $\tilde{\mathcal{V}}^*\equiv \mathbb{R}^+_p$. Also, by following the notes you linked and your answer, I understand that $\mathcal{Y}^*=-\tilde{\mathcal{M}}^*$.

Comment: Now, let's go back to the primal (1) and let's write the KKT conditions (Primal Feasibility, Dual Feasibility, Complementary Slackness). For any $(x^*,\nu^*,\mu^*)$ satisfying the KKT conditions, we have that $x^*$ is an argmax of the primal. Let $\mathcal{M}^*$ and $\mathcal{V}^*$ be the sets of $\mu$ and $\nu$ satisfying the KKT conditions, respectively. Is it true that $\mathcal{M}^*=\tilde{\mathcal{M}}^*$ and $\mathcal{V}^*=\tilde{\mathcal{V}}^*$?

Comment: @TEX I don't know what you mean by "$\tilde{\mathcal{V}}^*\equiv \mathbb{R}^+_p$", but not all $\nu \in \mathbb{R}^+_p$ solve the dual. As for your last question you did not introduce $\bar{\mathcal{M}}$, but solutions to the KKT conditions are primal/dual optimal.

Comment: Thanks. I got the point on "$\tilde{\mathcal{V}}^*=\mathbb{R}^+_p$". With regards to the other point, I define $\tilde{\mathcal{M}}^*$ and $\tilde{\mathcal{V}}^*$ as the set of $(\mu,\nu)$ satisfying the Lagrange dual problem $$\max_{\nu\geq 0, \mu} \min_x L(x,\nu,\,mu)$$. I define ${\mathcal{M}}^*$ and ${\mathcal{V}}^*$ as the set of $(\mu,\nu)$ satisfying the KKT conditions. Is it true that $\tilde{\mathcal{M}}^*={\mathcal{M}}^*$ and $\tilde{\mathcal{V}}^*={\mathcal{V}}^*$.

Comment: Yes, that is true. You should write down the KKT conditions for the dual problem to see that they are the same as the KKT conditions for the primal problem.